# Why does skipWhile behave differently in these examples?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

In the first example, my terminal outputs

```
next(1)
next(2)
next(3)
next(4)
next(5)
next(6)
next(7)
next(8)
next(9)
next(10)
completed
```

In the second example it will output

```
next(3)
next(6)
next(8)
next(9)
completed
```

I know the values are different in each, but I would expect the first example to have had filtering applied so it follows the logic within my `.skipWhile { $0 % 2 == 0 }` block

```
func skipWhile() {
    let bag = DisposeBag()

    Observable
        .from(Array(1...10))
        .skipWhile { $0 % 2 == 0 }
        .subscribe { print($0) }
        .disposed(by: bag)

    Observable
        .from([2,3,6,8,9])
        .skipWhile { $0 % 2 == 0 }
        .subscribe { print($0) }
        .disposed(by: bag)

}
skipWhile()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`skipWhile` is not `filter`. It skips elements at the start of the observable's lifetime while the predicate as true. As soon as an element comes along that no longer satisfies the predicate, it opens the flood gates and let everything else through.

Your first observable says "skip everything until the first odd number". The first element is odd, so nothing is skipped, and that's why you see all array elements being printed.

If you notice in your second observable, you didn't filter out even numbers (because there's an `8`). You merely skipped over elements until the first odd number (`3`), causing the `2` to be skipped.

### On a side note

`Int.isMultiple(of: )` has been added in Swift 5, and I suggest you use it in cases like this. It just makes it clearer, and side-steps errors caused by misreading `==` vs `!=`.

```
Observable
    .from(Array(1...10))
    .skipWhile { $0.isMultiple(of: 2) }
    .subscribe { print($0) }
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

You could even name your predicate:

```
let isEven: (Int) -> Bool = { $0.isMultiple(of: 2) }

Observable
    .from(Array(1...10))
    .skipWhile(isEven)
    .subscribe { print($0) }
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

Or my favourite, add it as a computed property:

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    var isEven: Bool { return self.isMultiple(of: 2) }
    var isOdd: Bool { return !self.isEven }
}

Observable
    .from(Array(1...10))
    .skipWhile(\.isEven)
    .subscribe { print($0) }
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

Comment: ah! yes! Thanks you so much, that makes perfect sense, I understand now :)